# Write schema for Spark dataframe (in code) from current dataframe's schema

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, schema

In cases when writing the entire schema for a Spark dataframe manually is not feasible (when there may be a lot of fields in the dataframe) and you have the expected schema for said dataframe, what is the most time saving way to declare the expected schema in code?

In more detail:

1. Say you have a dataframe with a lot of fields (may contain `MapType` and `ArrayType` `StructFields`) and because of the large number of fields, it's unfeasible to declare the entire schema as `val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("colName", ...`
2. You know that the current schema of the dataframe is the schema that you expect the dataframe to always have in the future.

For this, you want to automate the process of declaring the schema (like the code in point 1) in Scala so that the next time you have to declare the expected schema, you can save time. Is there a tried, tested way to do this?

For example, if the schema for the current dataframe is:

```
root
 |-- Names: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- additionalMetadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Get the schema in code as:

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("Names", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
    StructField("AdditionalMetadata", StructType(Array(
      StructField("value", StringType),
      StructField("key", StringType)
    ))),
    StructField("name", StringType)
  ))))
))
```

The schema represented in code can be used for enforcing schema when reading the dataframe like `spark.read.schema`.

**TLDR**: Given a Spark Dataframe, get the declaration of the schema in code.

**Update**
I see that `dataframe.schema` gives a similar output to what I desire. Here is an example of the output on printing `dataframe.schema`:

```
StructType(StructField(Names,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(AdditionalMetadata,StructType(StructField(value,StringType,true), StructField(key,StringType,true)),true), StructField(name,StringType,true)),true),true))
```

However, this does not compile. To make it compile, you have to do the following:

1. Add double quotes around the field name (i.e. "Names", "AdditionalMetadata", "value").
2. Put all elements inside every `StructType` inside an `Array`, `List` or `Seq` i.e. `StructType(StructField(Names,ArrayType....` -> `StructType(Array(StructField(Names,ArrayType....`.

As you can see, this is okay for small schemas but not scalable to do manually for big schemas.

However, **a possible solution** is to save to disk a subset of the data, just for it's schema. So when reading a new file, you enforce a schema on the new dataset using the schema of the subset you maintained. I do not prefer this solution because it feels hacky and am hoping to find a quick way to extract the code representation of the schema.

Comment: I disagree that this question is a duplicate. This answer gives a way to retain the schema in a JSON format which is *persistently storeable* - so you can verify the schema next time your Spark job runs. This is exactly what I wanted to understand how to do, and is different from the answer in the question this question is marked to be a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the schema of a dataframe `df` by using `df.schema`. This schema can directly be used in `spark.read.schema`, so there should be no need to obtain the schema as compilable code. For example:

```scala
val df = ...
val df2 = spark.read.schema(df.schema).csv(...)
```

To retain the schema for multiple runs you can save it as json using:

```scala
val jsonString = df.schema.json
```

This string you can now save to a file (or hard-code in the program) for later usage. Note that the json string also can easily be adjusted if wanted, same as if you had compilable code.

After converting the schema to json, to get it back to the correct type afterwards you need to do:

```scala
val schema = DataType.fromJson(jsonString).asInstanceOf[StructType]
```